# sortedByDescending list Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have this object list `List<ABC>`. I would like to sort the list by the latest updated date. How can I achieve that?

```
 v.sort((a, b) => a.updatedAt.compareTo(b.updatedAt));
```

I use above code to sort, but it not descending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v.sort((a, b) => b.updatedAt.compareTo(a.updatedAt))

Answer (score 0):

This fixed

```
v.sort((b, a) => a.updatedAt.compareTo(b.updatedAt));
```